# I want to know what it means (height,width)=img.shape[:2]

Tags: python, numpy

I don't know what that means

```
def rotate(img,angle,rotPoint=None):
    (height,width)=img.shape[:2]
    if rotPoint is None:
        rotPoint= (width//2,height//2)
    rotMate=cv.getRotationMatrix2D(rotPoint,angle,1.0)
    dimensions=(width,height)
    return cv.warpAffine(img,rotMate,dimensions)
```

I mean :

```
def rotate(img,angle,rotPoint=None):
    (height,width)=img.shape[:2]
```

I would like some explanations

Comment: You should tell us about the imports, what type is the 'img' object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what type the 'img' object is. What are you using? I'm assuming [`opencv`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/df2/tutorial_py_basic_ops.html) ?

Then the shape of the object holds a tuple `(rows, columns, channels)`. `(height,width)=img.shape[:2]` is an example of tuple unpacking, with it you extract the `rows` and `columns` values from the shape tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The `shape` property of the `img` object evidently is a list which contains some image data, the first two elements of which are here being copied into variables `height` and `width`.